# Load PHP page in div when I click link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to load a seperate php page into a div when I click on a div button.

Ie: #div1 opens up #display with one.php within, #div2 opens up #display with two.php, etc..

Any suggestions?

Comment: jquery's load: `$('#div1').load('one.php');`

Answer (score 2):

You could use AJAX For this:

```
$('#div1').on("click",function(){
    var url= "page1.php"; //insert your URL
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data){
           $('#div1').html(data); //copy and paste for your special case
      }
    });
});
```

**Documentation:**

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways. By "load PHP page in div", I will suppose you mean "load the output of a PHP page in div".

The simplest way, if you really just want to load some HTML response (without the need of generating a POST request), is to use jQuery's load function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div1').click(function() {
        $('#display').load('one.php');
    });
    $('#div2').click(function() {
        $('#display').load('two.php');
    })
    $('#div3').click(function() {
        $('#display').load('three.php');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try like below

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
 $('#display').load('one.php', function() {
    alert('Load was performed.');
   });
});

$('#div2').click(function(){
 $('#display').load('two.php', function() {
    alert('Load was performed.');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax for this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , or load: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's load method to load content on click event.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax for that:

```
$.post("GetData.jsp",
  { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
  function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  }
);
```